# jquery .animate() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I don't understand why my code doesn't work...

I want to animate the color of a title when clicked, and it doesn't work.

I reduced my page just to this simple part because the rest doesn't need animation and it's working fine.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49Zrf/)

HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<div id="Nav">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h2>Works</h2>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#Nav h2 {
    display: table;
    color: #353535;
}
#Nav h2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQUERY

```
function sortEvents() {
    $("#Nav h2").click(function () {
        $("h2").animate({ "color": "#f49d29" }, 1500);      
    })
}
```

Comment: jQuery alone cannot animate color. You need a plugin like https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle you haven't included jQuery; then `animate` using color can be only used by including [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) or jQuery colors:

> jQuery UI bundles the jQuery Color plugins which provides color
>   animations as well as many utility functions for working with colors.

Consider to color only the clicked element by using this as selector:

```
$("#Nav h2").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "color": "#f49d29"
    }, 1500);
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/49Zrf/5/

Comment: Thank you! I use "this" but for the example I was not worried about that. The full animation selects a lot more stuff and the "h2" was just an example.

Comment: @enikmaster ok, it was just an add :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Jquery.UI inorder to have color animation. Have Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49Zrf/4/) to demonstrate the same.

Code Snippet:

```
$(document).on('click','#Nav > h2', function () {
    $(this).animate({ "color": "red" }, 1500);      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard jquery library does not support color animation. Need to include jQuery UI to make it happen. http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: Thank you! Help appreciated.